# WCF primitive type vs complex type

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, system-design

I'm designing a WCF service that will return a list of objects that are describing a person in the system.

The record count is really big and there I have some properties like person's sex.
Is it better to create a new enum (It's a complex-type and consumes more bandwidth) named Sex with two values (Male and Female) or use a primitive type for this like bool IsMale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very little point switching to bool; which is bigger:

```
<gender>male</gender> (or an attribute gender="male")
```

or

```
<isMale>true</isMale> (or an attribute isMale="true")
```

Not much in it ;-p

> The record count is really big...

If bandwidth becomes an issue, and **you control both ends of the service**, then rather than change your entities you could look at some other options:

- pre-compress the data as (for example) gzip, and pass (instead) a `byte[]` or `Stream`, noting to enable MTOM on the service
- (or) switch serializer; proobuf-net has WCF hooks, and can achieve significant bandwidth improvements over the default `DataContractSerialier` (again: enable MTOM). In a test based on Northwind data [(here)](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) it reduced 736,574 bytes to 133,010. *and* reduced the CPU required to process it (win:win). For info, it reduces enums to integers, typically requiring only 1 byte for the enum value and 1 byte to identify the field; contrast to `<gender>Male</gender>`, which under UTF8 is 21 bytes (more for most other encodings), or `gender="male"` at 14 bytes.

However, either change will break your service if you have external callers who are expecting regular SOAP...

Answer (score 1):

The reason to not use an `enum` is that XML Schema does not have a concept equivalent to an `enum`. That is, it does not have a concept of named values. The result is that enums don't always translate between platforms.

Use a bool, or a single-character field instead.

Answer (score 1):

**I'd suggest you model it in whatever way seems most natural until you run into a specific issue or encounter a requirement for a change.**

WCF is designed to abstract the underlying details, and if bandwidth is a concern then i think a bool, int or enum will all probably be 4 bytes.  You could optimize by using a bitmask or using a single byte.

Again, the ease of use of the API and maintainability is probably more important, which do you prefer?

```
if( user[i].Sex == Sexes.Male )

if( user[i].IsMale == true; ) // Could also expose .IsFemale

if( user[i].Sex == 'M' )
```

etc.  Of course you could expose multiple.